# AWS for Android SDK host name error

Tags: android, amazon-s3, amazon-web-services, hostname

I'm trying to upload to AWS S3 by using thier AWS for Android SDK but both sample project within SDK and my project give the following error on devices while emulator runs without problem. So there's no problem with my AWS account.

"Host name may not be null."

Upload Code :

```
s3Client.createBucket(Constants.getBucket());
PutObjectRequest por = new PutObjectRequest(Constants.getBucket(), record.getFile().getName(), record.getFile());
s3Client.putObject(por);
```

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue has been solved on AWS Mobile Development Forum. The reason was that my device' language was set to Turkish which contains the letter ı, which was included in my bucket name while emulator's language was set to English.

```
myBucketName.toLowerCase(Locale.US);
// in sample project it's = ("my-unique-name" + ACCESS_KEY + SECRET_ACCESS_KEY).toLowerCase();
```